# Deploy a GitHub branch using heroku CLI

Tags: github, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I want to do this action:
[image]

using Heroku CLI.

If I have the remote git on my computer I can do `git push my-heroku-remote master`

But because my heroku app is already connected to the git project, I find this  approach redundant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the GitHub auto-deployment over the `git push heroku master` because it works great with a GitHub Flow (Pull Requests to master).  But if you would rather do manual deployments to Heroku from your dev machine you can fetch and push:

```
git fetch origin master:master
git push heroku master:master
```

(Assuming the GitHub remote is named `origin` and the Heroku remote is named `heroku`.)

Comment: Thanks, but this solves only part of the problem - the machine I'm running this on should be aware of the git project - whereas Heroku is already aware of it. So it's double configuration

Comment: @YardenST Can you provide more details?  I'm unclear on what you are looking for / trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes. We need to assume that the Heroku project has access to the git project. Therefore in theory - I should be able to run only `heroku ...` command that will build the app from the master branch. In your example, however - You are using the git command, which is I wish could be redundant as for my explanation. Because I'd like to have a build process that has not access directly to the git project.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it.  You want a Heroku CLI equivalent for the manual Deploy GitHub branch button.  But you don't want auto-branch deployment.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes something like `heroku  deploy:master -a myapp`

Comment: There isn't an out-of-the-box command for that.  But you can start a build from the API (which the CLI wraps): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#build-create  So you could create a Heroku CLI plugin that would do this.  So overall not trivial and really I'd recommend the branch auto-deployment instead.

Comment: Thanks was not aware of the api/plugin system. That can help

Comment: As far as I know, heroku CLI tool cannot do this, but the slack integration can.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/chatops#deploying-code-to-an-app

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://help.heroku.com/I3E6QPQN/how-do-i-force-a-new-deploy-without-adding-a-commit-to-my-github-repo):

This can be done with the [builds-create](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#build-create) Platform API endpoint.

There is a [Builds CLI plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds) that makes this easier:

```sh
heroku builds:create --source-url https://user:token@api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo name>/tarball/master/ --app <app-name>
```

Where user is your Github username and token is a Github personal access token ([reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens))